# How to pass input to beam.Flatten()?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I started using apache beam with python and I am stuck every 30 minutes. I am trying to flatten then transformation:

```py
lines = messages | 'decode' >> beam.Map(lambda x: x.decode('utf-8'))
output = ( lines
           | 'process' >> beam.Map(process_xmls) # returns list
           | 'jsons' >> beam.Map(lambda x: [beam.Create(jsons.dump(model)) for model in x])
           | 'flatten' >> beam.Flatten()
           | beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(1, 0)))
```

So after running this code I get this error:

```
ValueError: Input to Flatten must be an iterable. Got a value of type <class 'apache_beam.pvalue.PCollection'> instead.
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `beam.Flatten()` operation takes an iterable of PCollections and returns a new PCollection that contains the union of all elements in the input PCollections.  It is not possible to have a PCollection of PCollections.

I think what you're looking for here is the `beam.FlatMap` operation. This differs from `beam.Map` in that it emits multiple elements per input. For example, if you have a pcollection `lines` that contained the elements `{'two', 'words'}` then

`lines | beam.Map(list)`

would be the PCollection consisting of two lists

`{['t', 'w', 'o'], ['w', 'o', 'r', 'd', 's']}`

whereas

`lines | beam.FlatMap(list)`

would result in the PCollection consisting of several letters

`{'t', 'w', 'o', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd', 's'}`.

Thus your final program would look something like

```
lines = messages | 'decode' >> beam.Map(lambda x: x.decode('utf-8'))
output = ( lines
           | 'process' >> beam.FlatMap(process_xmls) # concatinates all lists returned by process_xmls into a single PCollection
           | 'jsons' >> beam.Map(jsons.dumps)  # apply json.dumps to each element
           | beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(1, 0)))
```

(note also `json.dumps`, returning strings, is probably what you want instead of `json.dump` which takes a second argument as the file/stream to write to).